# Odoo 10 - Use two models in a tree view

Tags: view, treeview, models, odoo-10

I have created a model named `Appointment` which stores appointment details of a `patient` whose details i am storing in the res.users table. I have used `Many2One` multiplicity between the `Appointment` and the `patient` using the `userId`.

Appointment model contains the following:

```
appointment_details = fields.Text(string='Appointment details', required=True)
appointment_date = fields.Date(string='Appointment date', required=True)
patient_user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='Patient id', default=lambda self: self.env.uid, required = True)
```

I added the following fields in the res.users model:

```
phone_number = fields.Integer(string='Phone number', required=True)
address = fields.Text(string='Address', required=True)
```

When displaying the `Appointment` details in the form view, the patient's name appears. But, i want to display his phone and address as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add following fields in your '**appointment**' class.
Note : keep the datatype same of res.users fields and appointment calss fields

```
phone_number = fields.Integer(string='Phone number',related='patient_user_id.phone_number')
address = fields.Text(string='Address',related='patient_user_id.address')
```